# Issue With Apache POI Jar

Tags: java

I am trying to do a file upload from html form and then use the Apache POI jars to parse the file. Please find the HTML code below,

```
<HTML>  
<HEAD>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</HEAD>

<BODY bgcolor="#E7EBEF">
  <CENTER><H1>Welcome To The Excel File Upload Page .</H1></CENTER>

    <form name="connectForm" id="connectForm" method="POST" action="/invoke/excelUtility.flowServices.dsp:readExcelWrapper" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <table>
              <tr>
                 <td><b><font color="red">Select Input File (.xlsx)</font></b></td>
                 <td><input type="file" name="fileData" id="fileData" 
                      accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><b><font color="red">Sheet Name</font></b></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="sheetName" id="sheetName" value="EIP_UPLOAD"></input></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><b><font color="red">Has Multiple Sheets</font></b></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="hasMultipleSheets" id="hasMultipleSheets" value="false"></input></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><b><font color="red">Has Column Header</font></b></td><td><input type="text" name="hasColumnHeader" id="hasColumnHeader" value="true"></input></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><b><font color="red">Web Flag</font></b></td><td><input type="text" name="webFlag" id="webFlag" value="true"></input></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><input type="image" src="images/submit-button.png" width="95" height="20"/></td>
              </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <br/>
   </form>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Now the file content is coming to the server as HttpInputStream. I am using that to create the workbook. Please find the code below,

```
    IDataCursor pipelineCursor = pipeline.getCursor();
    String  filePath = IDataUtil.getString( pipelineCursor, "filePath" );
    String  hasColumnHeader = IDataUtil.getString( pipelineCursor, "hasColumnHeader" );
    String  sheetName = IDataUtil.getString( pipelineCursor, "sheetName" );
    String  hasMultipleSheets = IDataUtil.getString( pipelineCursor, "hasMultipleSheets" );
    Object  contentStream = IDataUtil.get( pipelineCursor, "contentStream" );
    String  webFlag = IDataUtil.getString( pipelineCursor, "webFlag" );
    pipelineCursor.destroy();
    int rowCnt=0;
    String[]    columnNameList ={""};
    StringBuilder clnm=new StringBuilder("");

    String status="";

    XSSFWorkbook workbook=null;
    FileInputStream file=null;

    try {   
            if(contentStream!=null)
            {
                InputStream is=(InputStream)contentStream;
                workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(is);
            }
            else
            {
                file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
             }
            XSSFSheet sheet=null;

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook

                sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();

                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                int cellCnt=0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    if(rowCnt==0)
                    {  
                        clnm.append(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        clnm.append("\n");     
                    }   
                    cellCnt++;
                }
                rowCnt++;
            }

            columnNameList=clnm.toString().split("\n");  

            if(hasColumnHeader.equals("true"))
                    rowCnt=rowCnt-1;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            status=e.toString();
        }
```

PS : You can view the IDataUtil/IDataCursor APIs from the below link,

http://grandyop94.free.fr/wMe/7.1.2/7-1-1_Integration_Server_Java_API_Reference/index.html?com/wm/data/IDataUtil.html

Now If I am running the file in a stand alone way , that is from a file , it is working absolutely fine. No issues. But when I am trying to run from the Browser using file input tag , html, it is giving the below error,

"org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException: No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file"

Is there any issue with reading from the stream object here? Please help.

Comment: What is `contentStream`? Where is it defined? How do you assign a value to it? Please don't remove relevant parts from your code. It's best to create a [mcve].

Comment: contentStream is defined as an object (java.lang.Object). Then type casting done to InputStream.

Object contentStream = IDataUtil.get( pipelineCursor, "contentStream" );
   String webFlag = IDataUtil.getString( pipelineCursor, "webFlag" );

Actually this coding is done using the tool called webMethods.

Comment: I think , the stream is getting corrupted during the POST call. I am trying to write the data in sample.xlsx format and when I am trying to open the file , it says invalid format. My question is how can I pass the exact content from browser to the server.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. You have to [edit] your question and add the relevant code there. Note that if you are using libraries which are not part of standard Java you have to add relevant tags or explain which libraries you are using (e.g. `IDataUtil`).

Comment: Hi I have added the full code and provided the API documentation link. This is a custom API for SoftwareAG , which allows us to write Java Services. The IDataUtil API uses us to accept the input and outputs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sigh. I think you still don't understand. There is no way for us to know from the code you have given how the field `fileData` in the HTML form magically becomes the `contentStream` in your program. Until you provide each and every step from that form to that variable, nobody is going to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you upload .xlsx file, not .xls one.

Comment: Hi, I am uploading .xlsx file only. I think it has to do with the stream input coming from the form. It is not able to identify properly. Seems that the stream is getting corrupted during the transfer.